# Is XNU based on FreeBSD or OpenBSD?

Tags: freebsd, mac, openbsd, apple, bsd

I'm curious, is the [xnu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNU) kernel based on [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD), [OpenBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD), or some other [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) distribution?

Thank you,

James Pedersen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu

**What is XNU?**

XNU kernel is part of the Darwin operating system for use in macOS and iOS operating systems. XNU is an acronym for X is Not Unix. XNU is a hybrid kernel combining the Mach kernel developed at Carnegie Mellon University with components from FreeBSD and a C++ API for writing drivers called IOKit. XNU runs on x86_64 for both single processor and multi-processor configurations.